# Laravel Jetstream modal doesn't appear

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to re-use the Jetstream Dialog Modal, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the sample taken from the official docs

```
<jet-dialog-modal :show="modal" @close="modal = false">
           <template #title>
               Delete Account
           </template>

           <template #content>
               Test content
           </template>

           <template #footer>
               Cancel
           </template>
       </jet-dialog-modal>
```

When I set the modal property to true and inspect the DOM, body style is being appended with an overflow: hidden; However, the modal window doesn't show up. As an important note, I'm using the Inertia stack.

Answer (score 2):

I figured the issue was related to the layout. I forgot to include the
`<portal-target name="modal" multiple></portal-target>` in my custom layout.